Migration of ASP.NET MVC application to Azure Container app (Windows container)
I have an application in ASP.NET MVC & want to modernize it and move to cloud using Azure Container apps.
However I found Azure Container app will deployed app on linux container & my requirement is to deploy on Windows container.
Can we provision it? If anybody has a solid proof please do share.

Are you using CORE or .NET framework ?

Yes,you can deploy to Windows Container. Refer this MSDoc once.

@Harshitha it's a .net framework only.& Doesn't want to migrate into core I mean I just want to lift&shift to azure container app without modifying code.

@Harshitha I don't want to use web app.. simply I want to containerised .net MVC application & deploy it on azure container app to reduce efforts to convert MVC code to .net core & then deploy it on azure container app.

Web App might be the easiest way to do this because it is windows.  No need to create a container for it. For container apps - to my knowledge windows container are not supported yet. https://github.com/microsoft/azure-container-apps/issues/181
You could use AKS or Container instances. But Web app would be way easier here

@JulianHüppauff I'm not so sure on this link that you have shared. ...is it really correct or not however whatever resources I have gone through I found its compatible with some issues like docker image size cause since windows container internally uses linux it's ultimately taking space for windows & linux too..so may cause issue due to this..anyways if you came across any other solid proof on this please do share it.

Why are you not using app service, it is really one of the best choices for web applications. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/containers only Linux is supported.

Thanks @Julian Hüppauff for the comment.
As per the MSDoc Azure Container App doesn't support Windows Containers as of now.

Confidential containers on Azure Container Instances currently doesn't support Windows containers.


After this date, Windows Server 2016 images will no longer be supported..


Even I tried to publish it using the Windows Docker.



With the above setting I am able to deploy Docker Container to Windows (Container Registry), but not to Container App.




As of now AKS and Azure App Service support Windows Containers.

Thanks @John Kilmister for the explanation.

Azure App Service Plan supports both Windows and Linux containers (like AKS and ACA), whereas Azure Container Apps only supports Linux containers.

